# how to print special char in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example, one line of code in my function

```
 (message "char %c:%d" character count)
```

will print the counts for each character. For nonprintable chars, such as newline and tab, I want the output looks like:

```
 \n:4
 \t:6
```

instead of printing a newline and tab literally. how can I do that?

Comment: I don't think Emacs escapes characters this way ever. I've only seen it to use octal codes. Anyway, I think you can do this with `printf "%q" in Bash. So you could call shell command - whether this is a good solution is really up to the situation where you need it.

Comment: any other way is fine - just do not print them literally. It would be surprising that emacs doesn't have a builtin way to do this...

Comment: Hm... now that I try to find where Emacs does this conversion, it all goes deep into C code, and it doesn't seem to be possible to get that functionality out of there directly.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve *some* of this by let-binding certain variables before printing.

```
`print-escape-newlines' is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
Non-nil means print newlines in strings as `\n'.
Also print formfeeds as `\f'.
```

There's also:

```
print-escape-nonascii
   Non-nil means print unibyte non-ASCII chars in strings as \OOO.

print-escape-multibyte
   Non-nil means print multibyte characters in strings as \xXXXX.
```

These all work with `prin1`, so you can use the `%S` code in format. e.g.:

```
(let ((print-escape-newlines t))
  (format "%S" "new\nline"))
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @wvxvw

```
(defun escaped-print (c)
  (if (and (< c ?z)
           (> c ?A))
      (string c)
    (substring (shell-command-to-string (format "printf \"%%q\" \"%s\"" (string c)))
               2 -1)))
```

The substring part is to cut out extra stuff from printf's output. I don't have a great deal of knowledge about this command, so it might not be flawless.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some code somewhere in emacs that can do this for you, but one way would be to write a function that converts the special characters to a string:

```
(defun print-char(c)
  (case c 
    (?\n "\\n")
    (?\t "\\t")
    (t (string c))))
```

Note that you need to use string format rather than character because you're actually writing multiple characters for each special character.

Comment: thanks, but it's not ideal. there could be more special characters other than the newline and tab. it would be pain to list them all out in the function.